# Removing ASP.NET Label text from JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am removing some character from asp.net Label Text with JS, Its removing the text, but on code behind file its still having the text.
Below is my code

```
function GetClientID(id, context) {
            var el = $("#" + id, context);
            if (el.length < 1)
                el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
            return el;
        }

 var emaillbl = GetClientID("lblEmail").attr("id");//lblEmail is ID of asp.net Label control
```

$("#" + emaillbl).html($("#" + emaillbl).html("-",''));

and on my code Behind

```
if(lblEmail.Text != "")//This condition always getting false
{
}
else
{
}
```

I have also tried with these but no luck

```
 $("#" + emaillbl).text($("#" + emaillbl).html("-",''));

 $("#" + emaillbl).val($("#" + emaillbl).html("-",''));
```

this is my Label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$("#" + emaillbl).lenght`? It will tell you whether element matched is available in DOM. If available, then jQuery should work for `.html() or .text()`

Comment: Do you mean upon postback the text is till populated in the label?

Comment: its value is 1. I am correctly getting ClientID of my label

Comment: @geedubb yes on postback the text is still there

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi - Changes you are making will not be persisted after the postback as you are only making the client side changes.

Comment: Just want to point out that passing data around using the label control on asp.net is not a standard way to do things. It feels like the problem should be approached from a different angle.

Comment: @wizkid Is there any solution of this?

Comment: @rtpHarry what should I use instead of Label?My requirement is that user can't  edit the text

Comment: I did a quick search and it seems that the Label value is not included in the postback. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705615/asp-net-best-way-to-retain-label-text-value-between-postback-with-pagemethods suggests that you store your value in an `<asp:HiddenField>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<asp:HiddenField>` and also write the changed value in that field!

In code behind change your label with the value from your hiddenfield!

to write the value using jquery use:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="myHiddenField"/>

$('#<%= myHiddenField.ClientID %>').val(myNewValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out:-**

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#<%=lblEmail.ClientID%>").remove();
});
```

And if you want to reuse your code then,

```
function GetClientID(id, context) {
            var el = $("#" + id, context);
            if (el.length < 1)
                el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
            return el;
        }

var emaillbl = GetClientID("lblEmail").attr("id");

$("#" + emaillbl).remove();
```

Comment: I can't remove the label :(

Comment: What is the value of `$("#<%=lblEmail.ClientID%>").length`

Comment: Also, please share the asp tags as well

Comment: On postback the text is till populated in the label

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the previous value is stored in the viewstate. Add the below mentioned attribute value pair to the control to disable view state for the control.

```html
EnableViewState="false"
```